# Explain - inserts only one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, explain

I'm trying to manually save optimizer plan for further analysis, like this:

```
do $$
declare
tmp text;
begin
  explain
    select * from public.some_table where 1=2 into tmp;
  insert into public.plans(plan) values (tmp);
end; $$
```

But when I select it later, I see it only saved first row from the explain statement:

```
Result  (cost=0.00..82.97 rows=1 width=114)
```

How can I make it to save the whole plan?

Comment: You need a loop over the result of the explain. Each line of the plan output is one row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when i'm trying to do `(for c in (explain(...))` that it gives me syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `explain` cannot be used like e.g. a `SELECT` this is a bit tricky and you need dynamic SQL for this.

The following worked for me:

```
do
$$
declare
   plan_line record;
begin
   for plan_line in execute 'explain select * from public.some_table where 1=2' loop
      insert into plans values (plan_line."QUERY PLAN");
   end loop;
end;
$$
```

Having the statement to be explained in a string makes things a bit more complicated.

If I needed that on a regular basis, I would probably create a function that does this:

```
create or replace function explain(to_explain text)
  returns setof text
as
$$
declare
  plan_line record;
begin
   for plan_line in execute 'explain '||to_explain loop
      return next plan_line."QUERY PLAN";
   end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
insert into plans 
select * 
from explain('select ...');
```